# How to prevent construction with 0 args?

Tags: php

Consider the following class:

```
class Asterisk implements IExpr {
    /** @var string */
    protected $databaseName;
    /** @var string */
    protected $tableName;

    function __construct($database=null, $table=null) {
        switch(func_num_args()) {
            case 0:
                $this->databaseName = null;
                $this->tableName = null;
                break;
            case 1:
                $this->databaseName = null;
                $this->tableName = $database;
                break;
            case 2:
                $this->databaseName = $database;
                $this->tableName = $table;
                break;
            default:
                throw new \BadMethodCallException("Expected 0-2 args");
        }
    }

    public static function value() {
        static $value;
        if(!$value) $value = new self;
        return $value;
    }
}
```

I want to prevent developers from constructing a new instance of `Asterisk` with `0` args, without going through the `Asterisk::value()` method. The 0-arg case is special, and I only want one instance of it.

So how can I do this?

Comment: One thing you need to ask yourself whenever you hit a problem like this, is *why* you have that situation. Is there a more common design that solves your underlying problem? Is the "special" instance really the same kind of object at all? Or perhaps *all* instances of the object should be managed (suggesting a static factory, as in the answer below). Or are those NULLs some other default in disguise?

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, it is the same kind of object. The problem is twofold (1) efficiency; I want to discourage users from creating many instances of what is an immutable object, similar to Java's small integer boxing (2) there's only one scenario where the 0-arg version will produce a warning, but otherwise they behave the same. Splitting it into a 2nd class would create more complexity than it would remove I think. That said, I think I can spot that special case by adding another method instead of relying on reference equality.

Comment: If the efficiency argument applies to all the variants, then a private constructor + static factory is definitely the model to go for, because then you could optimise other common cases too: `static $instances; ... return $instances[$database][$table];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to define your own constructor then. PHP will still create an instance of the object if the user passes the wrong number of arguments. Make the constructor private, and instantiate from a static method. By making the constructor private, the public API default constructor won't be available to API users.

```
private function __construct($database=null, $table=null) {
    // ...
}


public static function newInstance() {
    if(func_num_args() > 0) {
        return new self(func_get_args());
    } else {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException("Expected 0-2 args");
    }
}


Asterisk::newInstance() // throws BadMethodCallException()

$ast = Asterisk::newInstance(1, 2); // works, returns an instance of Asterisk.
```

Comment: Good suggestion. That's cleaner than the solution I was imagining but it makes my API a little inconsistent if just this one class uses an 'alternative' constructor.

Comment: Yeah, having this distinct new way of constructing objects will probably seem odd to new users of the code.

Comment: Since there's no way in PHP of having both a private (0 argument) and a public (multi-argument) constructor, this seems like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake, there's another way we can do this with a bit of a hack:

```
class Asterisk implements IField {
    /** @var string */
    protected $databaseName;
    /** @var string */
    protected $tableName;

    /**
     * @param string $database Database name, or table name if 2nd arg is omitted
     * @param string $table Table name
     */
    function __construct($database, $table=null) {
        switch(func_num_args()) {
            case 1:
                if($database === null) throw new \BadMethodCallException("Table cannot be null");
                $this->databaseName = null;
                $this->tableName = $database;
                break;
            case 2:
                if($database === null || $table === null) throw new \BadMethodCallException("Database or table cannot be null");
                $this->databaseName = $database;
                $this->tableName = $table;
                break;
            default:
                throw new \BadMethodCallException("Expected 1 or 2 args");
        }
    }


    public static function value() { 
        static $value;
        if(!$value) $value = (new \ReflectionClass(self::class))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
        return $value;
    }
}
```

We can create a new instance of the class without calling the constructor.